# AndroidView focus in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-view, android-jetpack

I want to keep track of focus in `EditText` in an `AndroidView` composable like in legacy UI. I've tried `onFocusChange()` in `EditText` but that doesn't get triggered. Also `Modifier.OnFocusChange()` doesn't get triggered either. I don't want to use `TextField` cause I have some operations that have to be done in native `EditText`.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: it seems there are still problems with `AndroidView` and focus - even a year after this was posted. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241426920